# How to use AWS Secrets Manager Caching for Python Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am referring the `aws-secretsmanager-caching-python` [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/aws-secretsmanager-caching/) and trying to cache the retrieved secret from secrets manager however, for some reason, i am always getting timeout without any helpful errors to troubleshoot this further. I am able to retrieve the secrets properly if i retrieve the secrets from secrets manager (without caching).

My main function in lambda function looks like this:

```
import botocore
import botocore.session
from aws_secretsmanager_caching import SecretCache, SecretCacheConfig

from cacheSecret import getCachedSecrets


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = getCachedSecrets()
    print(result)
```

and i have created cacheSecret as following.

```
from aws_secretsmanager_caching import SecretCache
from aws_secretsmanager_caching import InjectKeywordedSecretString, InjectSecretString

cache = SecretCache()

@InjectKeywordedSecretString(secret_id='my_secret_name', cache=cache, secretKey1='keyname1', secretKey2='keyname2')
def getCachedSecrets(secretKey1, secretKey2):
    print(secretKey1)
    print(secretKey2)
    return secretKey1
```

In the above code, `my_secret_name` is the name of the secret created in secret manager and `secretKey1` and `secretKey1` are the secret key names which have string values.

**Error**:
{
"errorMessage": "2021-03-31T15:29:08.598Z 01f5ded3-7658-4zb5-ae66-6f300098a6e47 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Can someone please suggest what needs to be fixed in the above to make this work. Also, i am not sure where to define the secret_name, secret key names in case if we dont use decorators.

Comment: If your lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: It doesn't use any VPC configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda needs to `ack` the response within 3 seconds but the code can run longer.  The timeout can be configured in the function config:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html